# Solve initial-value quasilinear problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need help to solve initial-value quasilinear problem:
$xu_y - yu_x = u$, $u(x,0)=h(x)$

Here what I did: The initial curve $\Gamma: <x=s, y-0, z=h(s)> $

The characteristic equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=-y$, $\frac{dy}{dt}=x$, $\frac{dz}{dt}=z$.. So $x=-yt + s$, $y=xt$ and $z=h(s)e^t$. Solve for $s$ I get $s=\frac{x^2 + y^2}{x}$ then solution for this problem is 
$u=h(\frac{x^2 + y^2}{x})e^{y/x}$. Is it right? I am not sure because the answer from text book, PDE 4th Edition by Fritz John, is $u=h(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})e^{arctan(y/x)}$

Please help. 
Thanks

Comment: The solution to the system $\frac{dx}{dt} = -y$, $\frac{dy}{dt} = x$ is NOT $x=-yt+s$ and $y=xt$. It looks like you tried to solve by just "integrating", but $x$ and $y$ are clearly not constants! Do you know how to solve this system of ODE?

Comment: I have tried this $\frac{dx}{-y} = \frac{dy}{dx}$ and it become $x^2 + y^2 = constant$ then I am stuck. Please help

Comment: @ Joey Zou, thank for you hint. Here what I got: $x^2+y^2=s^2$ then $s=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} also $x=s cos(t)$, $y=s sin(t)$  from there I get  $t =acrtan(y/x)$. Solution is $u=h(s)e^t = h(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})e^{tartan(y/x)}$